# How to avoid xss attack in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 carbon?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

How to solve xss attack (injecting `"Alert"`) problem in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 carbon?

**Request script as follows:**

```
GET /carbon/generic/list.jsp?region=region3&item=governance_list_api_menu&key=api&breadcrumb=APIs%26%2339%3b)%3balert(76174)%3b%2f%2f&singularLabel=API&pluralLabel=APIs HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xx.xx.xx:9443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Cookie: region1_identity_menu=visible; menuPanel=visible; menuPanelType=main; JSESSIONID=55DB064DEF96C3060444A39F6A8412ED; requestedURI=../../carbon/admin/index.jsp; region1_configure_menu=none; region3_registry_menu=none; region4_monitor_menu=none; region5_tools_menu=none; current-breadcrumb=metadata_menu%252Clist_sub_menu%252Cgovernance_list_api_menu%2523
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could please guide me @Saranki Magenthirarajah  https://stackoverflow.com/users/8032605/saranki-magenthirarajah

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the issue you are facing? Did you observe any error trace in the network tab or carbon console? If so, attach those details to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wso2 APIM 3.0.0 the solution is released but not implemented in updated versions of wso2 (3.1.0,3.2.0) .this process is based on XSSValve.java : (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/stratos/site/trunk/content/apidocs/4.1.5/org/wso2/carbon/ui/valve/XSSValve.html#XSSValve() )
( https://github.com/kasunbg/carbon-kernel-4.x/blob/master/core/org.wso2.carbon.ui/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/ui/valve/XSSValve.java )
And also the configuration model has been changed refer to :
( https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/reference/understanding-the-new-configuration-model/)
So I fallowed steps below :
1.vi APIM-HOME/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/carbon.xml.j2

```
            <XSSPreventionConfig>
               <XSSPatternsLocation>${carbon.home}/repository/conf/security/xss-               
                patterns.properties</XSSPatternsLocation>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                 <Rule>allow</Rule>
                       <Patterns>
                    <!--Pattern>carbon/sequences</Pattern>
                    <Pattern>carbon/configadmin</Pattern>
                    <Pattern>carbon/localentries</Pattern>
                    <Pattern>carbon/api</Pattern>
                    <Pattern>carbon/proxyservices</Pattern>
                    <Pattern>carbon/resources</Pattern>
                    <Pattern>carbon/task</Pattern-->
       <Pattern>carbon/resources/update_text_content_ajaxprocessor.jsp</Pattern>
                     
        <Pattern>carbon/resources/add_text_resource_ajaxprocessor.jsp</Pattern>
                    <Pattern>commonauth</Pattern>
          </Patterns>
    </XSSPreventionConfig>
```

2.vi  APIM-HOME/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml.j2

Add fallowing line to host section
`<Valve className="org.wso2.carbon.ui.valve.XSSValve"/>`